# is it possible to have a scrollview inside an Activity?

Tags: android

I am writing a classroom mgmt app and have one activity that I'd like to put a ScrollView inside of. 
I want a scrollable list of students amongst a group of activities like adding grades or checking attaendance
and so forth.

All the examples I have found are of  ScrollView as its own entity and not part of something else.
Is what i want possible?  If so, how could I do it?

Thanks,
martin

Comment: check the listview concept once

Answer (score 1):

If you want scrollable list you should use ListView: you can override row appearance and all what you want. You can find many tutorials in web, for example http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html